Err:8 https://apt.packages.shiftkey.dev/ubuntu any InRelease Certificate verification failed
After upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am trying to run sudo apt-get update
and i get this error
Ign:8 https://apt.packages.shiftkey.dev/ubuntu any InRelease
Err:8 https://apt.packages.shiftkey.dev/ubuntu any InRelease
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The name in the certificate does not match the expected.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 13.107.246.45 443]

I tried to reinstall ca-certificates
sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates

but nothing changed ... same error

Have you tried updating your mirror in sources.list?

How i can do that?
I tried to change the server in: Software & updates --> Ubuntu Software --> download from --> then I press select the best server
and I get the same error message

Actually this was the issue and it looks that the domain is not working yet
the package shiftkeys is used by github desktop
This link was describe the issue also
link

This question is similar to: apt-get update failed because certificate verification failed because handshake failed on nodesource. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I ended up just running:
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/shiftkey-packages.list

to remove the file, and all my errors disappeared.
